# Python raw_input history storage

Tags: python, windows, readline

I am running python 2.7.11 On a windows server 2008 and I have a raw_input for username as follow:

```
username = raw_input('Username: ')
```

Python kindly keep an history of my entries (which is the same as the python interpreter). I have find that it uses readline to do so, but I didn't find much on it.

So my question is basically how and where is stored the history on my computer ?

Comment: The Windows command prompt is keeping a history of commands, not Python.

Comment: How is it possible that when I start my script with `python.exe main.py` and `Username:` ask me for my name this history is link to the Windows command prompt ? I have tried the history is only what I enter in python not in the Windows command prompt .

Comment: "Command Prompt" usually means cmd.exe, so the above comment by @ColinBasnett is incorrect. Input history and aliases are maintained by the console (i.e. conhost.exe) for each attached executable. F7 gives you a popup box to scroll through the current application's history. The doskey.exe program can write the history lines to stdout, e.g. `subprocess.check_output('doskey /history /exename=python.exe')`. The name "doskey" and the interface are a legacy of MS-DOS, but this is a Windows application using the console API.

Comment: So it's not python that does that but windows! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @eryksun: That should really be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Kevin, depending on what Eagain wants to do, it may be better to install [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline) and use it to [store a history file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#example). `doskey` can save the Windows console history, but it can't restore it because the console API doesn't have a function to do that (not even an undocumented function).